# Forcing bracket to go under cursor

Tags: vimrc

So I am trying out javascript on vim. It is great that it automatically indents the braces for me when I close them etc.. But I was typing some JS and got into a bracket muddle.
Here is what I had:

```
angular.module('functionalities', [])
.directive("entering", function() {_}
})
```

I have put an underscore to represent where my cursor was when I started typing, in this case it was on this line in between the two braces : `.directive("entering", function() {_}`

when I press enter the closing brace stays behind my cursor, is there a way to get it to go to the line underneath my cursor and indent correctly? like this:

```
angular.module('functionalities', [])
.directive("entering", function() {
    _
  }
})
```

When I close braces, it automatically indents them in the right place for me, I am not sure if this due to a plugin I may have installed like Surround.vim but in this kind of situation where I insert text before the brace, it put me into a muddle with my brackets.

Suggestions would be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: Are `autoindent` and `cindent` on? Try setting them on, maybe that will help?

Comment: Ok here is a hack in your vimrc add: `inoremap { {<CR>}<C-o>O` this means that every time in insert mode when you hit `{` vim will put a `{`, press Enter, put the closing `}` and open at line above it.  So....... actually instead of using the hack you can just train your fingers to hit `shift + O` after you hit enter.